# why don't i see a new jsp page when i click the fire button in the applet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, applet, httpconnection

I am trying to communicate with a `servlet` and `jsp` via an applet. When the button in the applet is clicked request is fired to the servlet and then i try to forward from that servlet to a jsp page. Though the request is made successfully to the servlet's `doGet` method,i neither see a servlet page in the browser nor a jsp page. why is that ? what am i missing ?

*applet button click code :*

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.out.println("pressed the button !");
    try {
          URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost:8084/poll/servlet_1").openConnection();
          connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
          InputStream response  = connection.getInputStream();
          connection.connect();
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*servlet code :*

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws 
        ServletException,IOException {
    System.out.println("---inside the doGet method of servlet----");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    writer.println("You just landed on a servlet from an applet !");
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp_1.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

*What i see in the server log is the message : `---inside the doGet method of servlet----`*

when i fire the event the first statement inside the `doGet` method gets printed but the request is not forwarded to the `jsp` page. why is that ?

Comment: There is one possibility that jsp_1.jsp is not relative to your current request. If you don't give "absolute path" of the JSP, server tries to lookup for jsp_1.jsp relative to current request URL path on request.requestDispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly you need to Redirect from an applet to servlet and then forward JSP page?

```
after your servlet response
.....redirect to jsp from applet.

 AppletContext appletContext = getAppletContext();
 appletContext.showDocument(new URL(getDocumentBase(), "yourJsp.jsp"));
```